# How can I find out the current status of the request?

Tags: python, file, time, python-requests, status

How can I view the current progress of this request? Nothing is shown until the file completes and I would like to set some sort of indicator if this request is still active.

```
import requests

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

datalist=[]
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)
    datalist.append(data.text)

with open('file_complete.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in datalist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: You can add a `print()` statement before the `requests.gets(url)` and after `datalist.append(data.text)`. At least you can track the progress by URL.

Comment: If you want the progress in the file to follow as well, you should nest the `with` statement in the `for` loop -- that way the results of each `requests.get(url)` will be written to the file every time it successfully `gets` the `url` (hint: if you do that you no longer need `datalist`)

Comment: @TimothyWong Can you please explain this a bit more? I'm not understanding. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post as an answer for better clarity

Comment: Are you downloading some big file?

Comment: @Mooncrater Yes I am downloading a big file

Comment: @mjebay7 I think you want to know how much of the file is downloaded. Look at `iter_content` functionality of `requests`. You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a print() statement before the requests.gets(url) and after datalist.append(data.text). At least you can track the progress by URL.

```
for url in urls:
    print("Getting " + url)
    data = requests.get(url)
    datalist.append(data.text)
    print(url + " successfully downloaded")
```

Your code, however, only writes to the file once **all** URLs have been downloaded. If the program fails at any point `file_complete.txt` will not be created. So I suggest writing to the file once any URL download is successful.

```
import requests

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

# datalist=[]  // No longer needed
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)

    with open('file_complete.txt', 'a+') as f:   #change to mode "a+" to append
        f.write(data.text + "\n")
```

Another improvement that can be made -- your code assumes that ALL URLs are valid. We can use a `try-except` block to catch errors.

```
import requests

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

# datalist=[]  // No longer needed
for url in urls:
    try:
        data = requests.get(url)
    except:
        printf(url + " failed")
        continue   #moves on to the next url as nothing to write to file

    with open('file_complete.txt', 'a+') as f:   #change to mode "a+" to append
        f.write(data.text + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

requests.get() is a blocking call. If you would like to have a bit more control you could send your requests in individual threads. You could also add [timeouts](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) if that is of concern. But no, there is no way to check progress of an in-progress get request.